# Console like Gnome Terminal for Windows

Tags: windows, terminal, shell, console, gnome-terminal

I'm looking for console like the [Gnome Terminal](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-get-started.html.en) for Windows to replace cmd.exe. I'd like to have tabs and easy copy&paste. Do you know a tool like that?

Comment: A terminal is not a shell.

Comment: And semi-transparent background! Just how can you hack without semi-transparent background?!?!/11

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I know the difference between a terminal and a shell, I still would like a terminal as simple and as powerful as gnome-terminal (or konsole) than can be plugged into many shells (like cmd or bash). Preferably not as clumsy as Console

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and see if that fits your needs.

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font, different window styles

Comment: I am elated by such features. Now, how to make sure my dad doesn't know? :P

Answer (score 45):

Found similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950/is-there-a-better-windows-console-window).
I'm the author of [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (open source Console Emulator).

ConEmu can be used with any console application or simple GUI tools (like PuTTY for example). ConEmu is a live project, open to suggestions.

A brief excerpt from the long list of options:

- Use any font installed in the system, or copied to a folder of the program (ttf, otf, fon, bdf)
- Run selected tabs as Administrator (Vista+) or as selected user
- Windows 7 Jump lists and Progress on taskbar
- Integration with [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) (useful in 64bit systems to run DOS applications)
- Smooth resize, maximized and fullscreen window modes
- Scrollbar initially hidden, may be revealed by mouseover or checkbox in settings
- Optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications
- User friendly text and block selection (from keyboard or mouse), copy, paste, text search in console
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 color
- Quake/tilde style ;)

Read Scott Hanselman's [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConEmuTheWindowsTerminalConsolePromptWeveBeenWaitingFor.aspx) about ConEmu.

Comment: If you like it - please upvote on SuperUser Community Promotion Ads - 2012: http://meta.superuser.com/a/5023/139371

Comment: Yep just found out about ConEmu. It should get much more attention. loving it

Answer (score 5):

[Mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) is a terminal emulator for Cygwin and Cygwin derivatives such as MSYS. It can be downloaded from here or it can be installed through Cygwin's setup.exe program, where it can be found in the Shells category. The Cygwin installer creates a shortcut for mintty in the Windows start menu.

Features include:

- Xterm-compatible terminal emulation.
- Native Windows user interface with a simple options dialog.
- Easy copy & paste.
- Drag & drop of text, files and folders.
- Ability to open files and URLs with Ctrl+click.
- Comprehensive character encoding support, including UTF-8.
- Wide character display and Windows IME support.
- Window transparency, including glass effect on Vista and 7.
- Options are stored in a text file. No registry entries.
- Small program size and quick scrolling.

Comment: Do I need to install Cygwin first?

Comment: Window transparency, but no tabs? :\

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a terminal emulator. A good cross-platform emulator is [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/).

Comment: This is actually terminal emulator for Cygwin

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) / [CygwinPorts](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/). Actually, I'm running RoxTerm instead of gnome-terminal, but the latter is also possible. This solution is somewhat heavyweight, but since I not only need the terminal emulation, but also the bash / perl / vim / gcc / make environment, X Window server et al., it perfectly fit my bill. And it gives you "the real thing", i.e. gnome-terminal, not something "almost like it".

Comment: First upvote three years later. :-D Actually, by now I no longer use XMing.